# Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs: - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter

I have set up my conda environment which includes numpy, pandas, matplotlib and scikit-learn. When i

```
conda install jupyter
```

, i get this error

```bash
(C:\Users\Welcome\Desktop\project\env) C:\Users\Welcome\Desktop\project> conda install jupyter

Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problemE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package jupyter-1.0.0-py27_4 requires python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0, but none od

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ jupyter is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ jupyter 1.0.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previou.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I am trying to resolve this over the past few days and ive also checked stackoverflow and tried few commands and i'm confused as to what im supposed to do. But still this issue is not resolved.

Should i use `pip install jupyter` if it doesn't work?

Can somebody help me resolve this??

Comment: Solved this by `conda install python=3.11 jupyter`